# Is there an alternative to .load() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there an alternative to .load() in jQuery?

Comment: the biggest problem you got in this question is, there are **two** `.load()` methods in jQuery.

Comment: I know of .load('filename');
enlighten me

Comment: @andy I did visit jquery, google, before I posted the question here.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) directly if you need additional control over what [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) offers.

There are also *other* [`$.ajax()` shorthand methods available](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/).

- [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
- [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)
- [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 3):

Use $.ajax instead of .load function. But make sure you specify the dataType as html for the ajax function.
.load is just a shorten version of $.ajax function where the dataType is html.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url to load',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(html) {
    ... rest of your code that should be added into the load function.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**for jquery lib > 1.7**

```
$('#test_image').on("load",function() {

alert("fully loaded !!!");   


});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test_image').ready(function() {
    alert("fully loaded !!!");   
 });
```

Try this it will work

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned you can use $.ajax() directly.

Here is an example of this.

```
function update_user_ajx(user_id){

 var data = { 
 username: $('#UsernamePost_' + user_id).val(), 
 password: $('#PasswordPost_' + user_id).val(),
 email:   $('#EmailPost_' + user_id).val(),
 accesslevel: $('#AccessLevelPost_' + user_id).val()
 };

 $.ajax({
  url: "/managesettings/updateuser/" + user_id,
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  success: function (html) {

   /* Replace Content */
   $('#UpdateUsers').html(html);

   /* Try Fade In */
   $('#UpdateUsers').fadeIn('slow'); 
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: This is actually a very bad way to pass the `data` argument, you should use an object rather than forming the string yourself, or call [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  For example, what if my password has a `&` in it?

Comment: @Nick Craver: Thanks for pointing this out, i have modified my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something to happen on page load, do it relative to the document.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var var_name = $(this).find(".div_class").children(".child_div").height();
    $(this).find(".div_class").css("min-height", var_name);
});
```

Here I use the `find()` function with the document as relative parent, instead of using `load()` with the div as the relative parent.